# JavaScript triangle wrong direction how to make it correct?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript question, I want to make a Triangle like this

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
```

this is my code which makes opposite direction

```
    for(let i = 0;i<=5;i++){
        let str = "";
        for(let j = 0;j<i;j++){
            str += "*";
        }
        console.log(str)
    }
```

I wanna use for loop to make this triangle down bellow instead of using "repeat".

```
    for(let i = 0;i<=5;i++){
        let str = "";
        str = " ".repeat(5-i);
        str2 = "*".repeat(i);
        console.log(str+str2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
for(let i = 0;i<=5;i++){
    let str = "";
    for(let j = i;j<5;j++){
        str += " ";
    }
    for(let j = 0;j<i;j++){
        str += "*";
    }
    console.log(str)
}
```

This method can be used in all other programming languages, cause there's no special js syntax or special js built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use for loop with ternary operator

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  let str = "";
  for (let j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
    str += j < 5 - i ? " " : "*";
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `padStart` method

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  let str = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    str += "*";
  }
  console.log(str.padStart(5, " "));
}
```

Further simplify to one liner

```js
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      console.log('*'.repeat(i).padStart(5, " "));
    }
```